# fstream::exceptions unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, exception, fstream

In the code below; any idea why the `ifs` becomes bad when std::copy is performed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::fstream ifs(argv[1], std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    std::fstream ofs(argv[2], std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc | std::fstream::binary);

    ifs.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

    std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> begin(ifs);
    std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> end;

    std::ostream_iterator<char> begin2(ofs);

    ifs.exceptions(std::fstream::badbit | std::fstream::failbit);
    ofs.exceptions(std::fstream::badbit | std::fstream::failbit);

    if(!ifs)
        std::cerr << "ifs bad" << std::endl;
    if(!ofs)
        std::cerr << "ofs bad" << std::endl;

    try {
        std::copy(begin, end, begin2);
    }
    catch(...) {
        if(ifs.bad())
            std::cerr << "exception: ifs bad" << std::endl;
        if(ifs.fail())
            std::cerr << "exception: ifs fail" << std::endl;
        if(ifs.eof())
            std::cerr << "exception: ifs eof" << std::endl;
    }

    if(!ifs)
        std::cerr << "ifs bad" << std::endl;
    if(!ofs)
        std::cerr << "ofs bad" << std::endl;

    //ofs << ifs.rdbuf();
}
```

Here is the output I get.

```
~$ cp fstream.cpp ~/tmp/fstream/
~$ g++ -ggdb -O0 fstream.cpp

~$ ./a.out a.out xxx.ooo
exception: ifs fail
exception: ifs eof
ifs bad
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (default constructed) `end` iterator you've given as the place to stop copying will only compare equal to the other iterator when attempting to read the specified data from the file fails. In this case, it's converted all the data in the file and reached EOF. That means everything has succeeded, *but* the stream is now in a fail state, so until or unless you reset it, you won't be able to do anything else with that stream.

You've also misinterpreted things a bit: `!stream` is equivalent to `stream.fail()`, but that's *not* the same as `stream.bad()`. `stream.bad()` means there's been a serious failure such as a hard drive dying while you were trying to read from it. `stream.fail()` can mean something much milder (or even normal) such as an attempted conversion failing, possibly because you're read some data that can't be converted to the target type (e.g., the stream contains "one" and you're trying to read an `int`) or because (as in this case) you've reached the end of the file.

Bottom line: iostreams exceptions are only rarely of much use. Some of the exceptions are defined to be thrown in perfectly normal, expected cases.

Comment: !stream is the equivalent of stream.fail(), not !stream.good().  In
practice, stream.good() is useless, since it returns false if any of the
status bits (including eofbit) are set.  The general rule is: treat the
stream as a boolean until it fails, then use the various functions
(bad(), eof()) to determine why it failed.

And with regards to exceptions, you're pretty much right.  The only
exception might be badbit: if something serious goes wrong with the
stream, an exception might be justified.

Comment: @James: Oops -- right about stream.fail(). An exception for badbit would make sense, but (at least if memory serves) to enable it, you have to enable the others as well...

Comment: Thanks Jerry & James ... its been educational!